# Does not keep current identity value of table when deploy sql server project to exists database on visual studio

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

Does not keep current identity value of table when deploy sql server project to exists database on visual studio

Table1: current identity value 5, max(Id) = 3

Step 1: add field to table1 on visual studio

step 2: public to Database existed in sql server

- Generate script public: check script

  - Create table tmp_ms_xx_table1
  - Insert data from table1 to tmp_ms_xx_table1
  - Drop table1
  - rename table tmp_ms_xx_table1 to table1

After public database: Table1 current identity value 3, max(Id) = 3

Expected: Table1 keep current identity value 5 after public database using tools not script

Comment: Why do you care about the original current identity value as long as the new one does not conflict with actual data in the table?

Comment: Answered on msdn [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87ebee2a-88ce-4d56-8990-bc1b74eb9027/does-not-keep-current-identity-value-of-table-when-deploy-sql-server-project-to-exists-database-on?forum=ssdt)